# Number of epimorphisms of free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How many epimorphisms of free groups of rank 3 to $S_4$ exist? How many of them have the same kernels?

Comment: I can think of 24 epimorphisms offhand. There are probably many more.

Comment: when do we say to epimorphisms are the same?

Comment: This is very badly worded!

Answer (score 1):

Using [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/), I checked that there are $10\,080$ ordered triples of elements in $S_{4}$ that generate $S_{4}$. I suppose this means there are as many epimorphisms.

Here I assume three generators $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ of the free group $F$ are given, and we say that two morphisms are the same if they have the same values on the $x_{i}$.

Comment: Did you take into account two of the generators being the same?

Comment: Yes, all triples.